# What's the grammatical function of "not" and "to" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, parts-of-speech

What's the grammatical function of *not* and *to* in this sentence?

> It is legitimate for Slovenia not to allow the merger.

How do I analyse the verb phrase? *Allow* is the headword, but what are *not* and *to*?

Answer (score 2):

"to" is part of the "to allow" construction, the infinitive of the verb. The "not" simply negates (i.e. says "do the opposite") to this.

It would be equivalent to say this:

> It is legitimate for Slovenia to prohibit the merger.
>   It is legitimate for Slovenia to disallow the merger.

Answer (score 0):

**to** is a preposition. However, in this case **to** simply acts as a marker of the infinitive verb **to allow**.

**not** is usually considered an adverb. In this case it negates the infinitive **to allow**.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with a part of your first statement: "'to' is a preposition." Here, "to" *is* an infinitive marker, but not a preposition. Consider "All eyes look to Slovenia to merge." The first "to" is a preposition and could be replaced with other prepositions "toward," "for" or "at." The second "to" is used to mark the infinitive, and therefore could not be replaced with a preposition.